# Pybot - how to specify an xpath for an "a href" link

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, robotframework

I am trying to run a very simple test with pybot using the xpath but for some reason it keeps saying that my xpath is not a valid, even though I am following the documentation straight from http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html

This is all I have in my test:

```
Temp test
    Set Selenium Timeout   60s
    Set Selenium Speed   1s
    Open Browser  http://google.com  chrome
    Click Link  xpath=//a[@href=‘https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm&authuser=0']
    Sleep 3s
    Close All Browsers
```

But for whatever reason it keeps complaining

Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@href=‘/‘] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[@href=‘/‘]' is not a valid XPath expression.

I have seen other people follow the same format with no issues. I have also never had issues with xpath expressions for selenium with java in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how your opening quote is different from the closing one?

Change the `‘` in your syntax to a proper `'` -- and check that the close-quote in your real code is also a genuine ASCII-character-39 single-quote, not some fancy Unicode curly created by being copied/pasted through Microsoft applications or such.

Comment: wow, for some reason textedit is converting ' to ‘. Didn't even catch that, thanks so much

Comment: *nod* -- there's a reason a programmer's editor is the right tool for programming. :)